Inquiries Regarding the Submodule Structure of $ _{\mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{Q} $
As is well known, any cyclic submodules of $ _{\mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{Q} $ are superfluous. Here is a proof.
This raises the following questions:

Are all proper submodules of $ _{\mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{Q} $ also superfluous?

What do the submodules of $ _{\mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{Q} $ look like?"


Finitely generated submodules of $_{\mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{Q} $ are invariably superfluous, as these submodules are necessarily cyclic. This raises the question: what are the characteristics of non-finitely generated submodules of $ _{\mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{Q} $?

The answer to the first question is “no”. For example, let $A$ be the subgroup of dyadic rationals (i.e., with denominator a power of 2), and let $B$ be the subgroup of rationals with odd denominator. Then $\mathbb{Q}=A+B$.
The second question already has several answers on MSE, so I won’t add another, but see this question for the case of subgroups that contain 1. The general case follows easily from that.

Thank you most sincerely.
